# Cytoscape.js extension for more flexible coloring of edges

Tags: cytoscape.js

I'm using cytoscape.js to draw a graph. I'd like to do some fancier coloring of my edges similar to this:

[image]

I can't find any existing extensions for this, and the docs are pretty unclear on how I might write one to do something like this. I could probably hack this particular dashed style with two edges and some dash config-ing, but...thats hacky. Is there a way to do this correctly, or am I SOL?

Answer (score 1):

Visual style features need visual style properties and renderer support. Extensions are usually for layouts or interactive widgets (e.g. tooltips).

If you want particular style properties, you should define them in a feature request in the issue tracker. PRs are always welcome, but it’s good to define the feature well first so we can discuss and iterate on the API design beforehand.

There’s a lot going on in the picture, but maybe you mean something along the lines of a line-dash-background-color property?  It’s also not clear to me what the usecase is for having the alternating colours. In any case, start by defining the property or properties in a Github issue and we’ll go from there.

Comment: Thanks, I went ahead and opened an issue with some more detail about my usecase: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/2508